How to embed a flutter app in a normal dart web project and interop with it
I find flutter can export api to js :

Export the api to js through @js.JSExport() in the flutter app
Write in index.html js, and call the js api exposed by flutter in the previous step.


ref: https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/web_embedding/element_embedding_demo
ref: <github.com/dart-lang/web/example>

But, because dart can develop web (reference: github.com/dart-lang/web/example),
I hope to skip js and directly integrate flutter in dart's web development. Is there any good way? imaginary code：
void main() {
  final div = document.querySelector('div')!;
  div.text = 'Text set at ${DateTime.now()}';

  div.className = 'btn';

  document.body!.appendChild(div);

  // how to do this???
  document.body!.appendChild(SomeFlutterWidget());
}

I know https://github.com/schultek/jaspr can do it , but jaspr rewrite dart compiler, i want find a normal dart method
